How do I diagnose MySQL failing to load my plugin?
I am working on creating a MySQL authentication plugin. Referencing the official documentation, I created my source file and registered it in CMakeLists.txt as follows:
MYSQL_ADD_PLUGIN(
  auth_token
  auth_token.cc 
  MODULE_ONLY
  LINK_LIBRARIES jwt-cpp::jwt-cpp
)

After compiling MySQL from source along with my plugin (as instructed), I installed the server then started the daemon with the --plugin-load command line option:
./bin/mysqld --user=mysql --plugin-load=auth_token.so &

Finally, I created a user as follows:
CREATE USER 'token_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_token

Now when I try to connect to the server using token_user in Workbench, I get the following response:
Your connection attempt failed for user 'token_user' to the MySQL server at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306:
 Authentication plugin 'auth_token' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.

I executed SHOW PLUGINS and confirmed that the result set contained a row for my plugin:



Name
Status
Type
Library
License




auth_token
ACTIVE
AUTHENTICATION
auth_token.so
PROPRIETARY



I also confirmed that the plugin file exists (located at /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/auth_token.so), and there are no errors reported in the standard output of mysqld or in syslog.
How do I troubleshoot this?

The error message is ambiguous and a little misleading, which makes it difficult for new plugin developers (like myself) to properly diagnose. Reading about Authentication Plugin Client/Server Compatibility set me down the right path:

The general compatibility principle for a successful client connection to a given account on a given server is that the client and server both must support the authentication method required by the account. Because authentication methods are implemented by authentication plugins, the client and server both must support the authentication plugin required by the account.

When I realized that server plugins can require a particular client plugin as a prerequisite for authentication, I was able to better traverse the MySQL source code, plugin API, and documentation to find the root of my problem.
Eventually I found the client_auth_plugin property from the st_mysql_auth struct. The documentation defines this property as follows:

A plugin that a client must use for authentication with this server plugin. Can be NULL to mean "any plugin".

As it turns out, I had mistaken this property as my server-side plugin's name and set it to a non-null value. Because it was not set to null, it signaled to the MySQL client that a client plugin called "auth_token" was required to authenticate.
So when MySQL Workbench displayed the error message "The specified module could not be found", what it really meant was "The specified client module could not be found on the local machine."
